# Удивительное рядом. Хитрый id для элементов в XHTML

Tags: xhtml

Наткнулся на такую особенность.
Если элементу (пока тестировал на div и h1) задать id="adbar", то этот элемент не будет отображаться независимо какие свойства ему прописывать в css или даже если не прописывать вообще. Тестировал на Хроме и Мозиле последних версий. В нете информации не нашел по этому поводу. Может вы знаете откуда такие "приколы" берутся. И есть ли еще что-то такое?
Текст разметки на всякий случай:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Хитрый ID</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="adbar">
Тут надобно выводить что нибудь полезное...
<br/>Но по неведомым причинам этот блок не выведется О_о
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Валидацию проходит, что интересно. Пытался перекрыть стилями, например при помощи z-index. Без результата :)

Comment: Помню как то тоже мучался с div с id b**adblock** :)

Comment: Хорошо, что есть теперь такие ресурсы как этот

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это у вас блокировщик рекламы или userscript удаляющий рекламные блоки.

http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=1382

http://userscripts.org/topics/33115?page=1#posts-158425

Comment: И действительно, спасибо за ответ! Надо будет просмотреть список заблоченных id на будущее